# Why can't I use object keys which are stored as values in another object?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, javascript-objects

I'm making a chrome extension and two of the js files are-

- constants.js
- main.js

In constants.js, I've defined an object -

```
var infoPostJsonParamNames = {"pid" : "PID",
                              "title" : "title_value",
                              "price" : "price",
                             };
```

And in main.js, I'm using the values in infoPostJsonParamNames as keys of other objects, like -

```
    dataI = new Object();
    dataI.infoPostJsonParamNames["title"] = "Title value";
    dataI.infoPostJsonParamNames["cost"] = 12.34;
```

The reason behind doing this is that I've to use the same names of the keys (for example in POST requests), i.e. *PID, title_value and price*, in many places in the code but it may change in the future, for example, *title_value can become TITLE_v*.
So I am trying to avoid changing them in many places by changing them in only one place, i.e. in the object `infoPostJsonParamNames`.

But doing this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined
```

Comment: `dataI[infoPostJsonParamNames["title"]]` or `data[infoPostJsonParamNames.title]`

Comment: and for the sake of somebody working on the code in the future, pick a shorter name.

Comment: @Pointy oops, that worked! Thanks

Comment: @Pointy The line after var infoPostJsonParamNames, is var ipjpn = infoPostJsonParamNames;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to set a property name dynamically. You have to use bracket access; The following example should clarify it.

```
dataI = new Object(); // or {} for style points;
var titlePropertyName = infoPostJsonParamNames.title;
dataI[titlePropertyName] = "Title value";
```

What your code was previously doing was looking for a property called `infoPostJsonParamNames` in your `dataI` object. That property didn't exist so it caused an error when it tried to access a sub property called `title`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `infoPostJsonParamNames` initialisation inside `dataI` scope.

```
dataI = {};
dataI.infoPostJsonParamNames = {};
dataI.infoPostJsonParamNames["title"] = "Title value";
dataI.infoPostJsonParamNames["cost"] = 12.34;
```

By the way, you can do the same like this:

```
dataI = {
  infoPostJsonParamNames: {
    title: = "TitleValue",
    cost: 12.34
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using `infoPostJsonParamNames` as an easy way to allow the HTTP parameter names to be changed from a single place.